# Google APIs Adding a contact using PeopleService

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-people-api

I have a question about how correctly add a contact to Google Contacts using Google API.
For authorization I use external Json file Generated.
When I execute it , it doesn't give any mistakes but No Contact is Added to Google Contacts.
What can be wrong with the code?
Please find code below

Thanks

```
        private async Task Run()
    {

        GoogleCredential credential;

        using (Stream stream = new FileStream(@"D:\project1.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream);
        }

        string[] scopes = new string[] {
        PeopleServiceService.Scope.Contacts,
        PeopleServiceService.Scope.ContactsReadonly,
        PeopleServiceService.Scope.ContactsOtherReadonly,
        };

        credential = credential.CreateScoped(scopes);

        BaseClientService.Initializer initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = (IConfigurableHttpClientInitializer)credential,
            ApplicationName = "Project1",
            GZipEnabled = true,
        };

        PeopleServiceService service = new PeopleServiceService(initializer);

        Person contactToCreate = new Person();

        List<Name> names = new List<Name>();
        names.Add(new Name() { GivenName = "Alex", FamilyName = "Breen", DisplayName = "Alex Breen" });
        contactToCreate.Names = names;

        List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers = new List<PhoneNumber>();
        phoneNumbers.Add(new PhoneNumber() { Value = "11-22-33" });
        contactToCreate.PhoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;

        List<EmailAddress> emailAddresses = new List<EmailAddress>();
        emailAddresses.Add(new EmailAddress() { Value = "AlexBreen@mail.com" });
        contactToCreate.EmailAddresses = emailAddresses;

        PeopleResource.CreateContactRequest request = new PeopleResource.CreateContactRequest(service, contactToCreate);

        Person createdContact = request.Execute();

        Console.WriteLine(request);

    }
```

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OECc.png)

[Metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnzVf.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go though your service object.

```
    var request = service.People.CreateContact(new Person()
    {
    Names = new List<Name>() { new Name() { DisplayName = "test"}}

    // Fill in the rest of the person object here.

    });

    var response = request.Execute
```

Make sure you are checking google contacts from the same user you are authenticating your application from.

The response should be returning the new user.

## all contacts for a user

You can also test it by doing. This will give you a list of the users inserted for the user you have authorized.

```
var results = service.People.Connections.List("people/me").Execute();
```

## who is the current user

```
var results = service.People.Get("people/me").Execute();
```

var results = service.People.Connections.List("people/me").Execute();

## service accounts

A service account is not you. Think of a service account more as a dummy user it has its own Google contacts account.  When you insert into it you are inserting into the account owned by the service account.

If you have google workspace you can set up domain wide deligation to the service account and then delegate to users on the domain and add contacts to their google contacts within the domain.

You can not use a service account to write to a standard google gmail user's google contacts.  For that you would need to use Oauth2 and authorize the user to access their google contacts.

Comment: it gives me following error : Must specify a non-metadata contact field on the person. [400]
Errors [
        Message[Must specify a non-metadata contact field on the person.] Location[ - ] Reason[badRequest] Domain[global]
]

Comment: you need to add the rest of the object I just gave  you a start.

Comment: Now it doesn't give any mistake but still doesn't create a new contact as previously. Maybe I should wait for some time, because I created json file around a hour ago?

Comment: Is there any option to debug it?

Comment: Are you sure your logged in with the same user?  Try and revoke the authorization and login again.  It should insert it into the user you are using.   I assumin you are using a desktop app right?

Comment: Yes, console application as a test

Comment: I generated output json file as you can see it above and linked it

Comment: Just check response it should be returning the new person object.  Check edit I gave you a couple of other methods you can try.  I suspect you are not checking the same user your are logged in as.  This is going to insert into the current users contacts account If your checking the wrong user on the web app your not going to be seeing them.

Comment: If your using a service account your inserting into the service accounts account not your personal account.

Comment: Yes, there is a return. One of returns is Names Count=1

Comment: Thanks for your help, but how to understand which user to check. I mean I used email account to create that project and generate Json file. So if I am not wrong then I should check the contact for that email?

Comment: DaImTo, I think you are right, I am using service account but how to change it to the account I want? Thanks

Comment: No, service account email addresses can't be changed at all. 
They are not a part of your domain and so can not be given a different email addres and 
Service accounts do not have passwords, 
and cannot log in via browsers or cookies. 
Service accounts are associated with public/private RSA key pairs that are used for authentication to Google, and for signing data.

Comment: Check my update your going to need to use Oauth2.  unless you have a google workspace domain account.

Comment: Thanks DaImTo, it helped me a lot. After I used Oauth2 all 's going well and contacts are finally coming under my gmail account. Thank you very much!

Comment: Im happy to help remember to accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments on the previous answer:

- You are inserting contacts to a service account

To use your own account you have to create an [OAuth client ID](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#oauth-client-id) and then use the `credentials.json` to authorise on the code.

There is no C# sample on the [People API samples](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/js) but you can check on how to use this credentials based on the [.NET quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet) for Drive API but without using Drive API scopes and code.

Basically using this part of the code:

```
UserCredential credential;

using(var stream =
  new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
  // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
  // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
  string credPath = "token.json";
  credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
    Scopes,
    "user",
    CancellationToken.None,
    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
  Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
}
```

Comment: I did the same thing, I created json and each time use it to authorize my console when I run it, but still no contacts on the web site, but I can see then using following code:             PeopleResource.ConnectionsResource.ListRequest peopleRequest = service.People.Connections.List("people/me");
peopleRequest.PersonFields = "names,emailAddresses";
ListConnectionsResponse response = peopleRequest.Execute();
IList<Person> people = response.Connections;

Comment: So there s only one question, how to be able to share contacts between 'service account' and gmail account

Comment: can you please provide the structure of the credentials.json file?